# How to repeat one but continue with the others in an RxJava Iterable Observable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

Say I have an Observable that I created from an iterable or an array. If I map that observable to a method that returns something, how can I retry that behavior if I get a value that I don't like while also continuing on with the items in the iterable/array for which I received a value I did like?

Here is come seudo-code to portray what I'm talking about:

```
Observable
  .fromIteratable(values)
  .map(value -> getSomeDataFromAnAPI(value))
  .retryIf(value -> value != somethingIWant)
  .delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I'm looking for how to accomplish the "retryIf" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Put a loop around the call and return on a desired value:

```
Observable
.fromIteratable(values)
.map(value -> {
    while (true) {
        Data d = getSomeDataFromAnAPI(value));
        if (d == somethingIWant) {
            return d;
        }
    }
}
.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Depends on what your code does. If you have blocking or long running code, you need a way to stop your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like an emitted value, you could reject it (forcefully!) by mapping it to an error, and then using the `retryWhen()` operator to retry.

```
Observable
  .fromIterable( values )
  .flatMap( value -> getSomeDataFromAnAPI( value )
                       .doOnNext( value -> {
                          if ( value != somethingIWant ) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("undesired");
                          }
                       })
                       .retryWhen( throwable -> throwable.delay( 10,  TimeUnit.SECONDS) );
```

This will retry the item returning the bad value until it returns a good one.

Note that `flatMap()` will attempt each request on the default scheduler, leading to a number of parallel requests. You can add a parameter to limit the parallelism.